# Cannot parse month three letter month with locale en

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to parse a date having the form *2018 30 Oct 19:30* with Moment.js. The format for this should be `YYYY dd MMM HH:mm`. This is not working, and I have identified the problem to the *Oct* part of the string, see the below snippet:

```js
console.log('locale: ' + moment.locale());
console.log('\'2018 31 Oct\' valid? ' + moment('2018 31 Oct', 'YYYY dd MMM').isValid());
console.log('\'2018 31\' valid? ' + moment('2018 31', 'YYYY dd').isValid());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Given that the locale is *en* (which I understand is what you get when using Moment.js without all locales) I cannot understand why *2018 31 Oct* fails to parse with the format `YYYY dd MMM`. According to [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) `MMM` is the format to use for three letter months.

What goes on here that I don't understand, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Strangely, this works:  `console.log('\'Oct 2018 31\' valid? ' + moment('Oct 2018 31', 'MMM YYYY dd').isValid());`

Comment: This worked `console.log('\'2018 31 Oct\' valid? ' + moment('2018 31 Oct', 'YYYY DD MMM').isValid());`

Comment: Just a minor misreading of the docs. By the way, you can use `.parseFlags()` on the moment object for details that might help with figuring out why something didn't parse.

Comment: Thanks, my bad was that I started from a Java style format, wher both YYYY and DD where in lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dd` is the Day of Week (Su Mo ... Fr Sa), while you need Day of Month (`DD`).